# JQuery - change multiple background images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background

I have a CSS code that creates a frame using 8 images:

```
background-image: url(images/blue/tl.png), url(images/blue/tr.png), url(images/blue/bl.png), url(images/blue/br.png), url(images/blue/t.png),url(images/blue/b.png),url(images/blue/l.png),url(images/blue/r.png);
background-position: top left, right top, bottom left, bottom right, top, bottom, left,right;
background-repeat:  no-repeat,no-repeat,no-repeat,no-repeat,repeat-x,repeat-x,repeat-y,repeat-y;
```

My goal is to make a JQuery program, that can change the sources to different images. I have a problem defining the change in JQuery for multiple background images. I always end up with only one image changing.

JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#red").on("click", function(){
            $("#outer-frame").css({'background-image': "url(images/red/tl.png)", 'background-image': "url(images/red/tr.png)"});
            $("#outer-frame").css({'background-position': "top left", 'background-image': "top right"});
        });
```

I would really appreciate if somebody who knows how to do this would help me.
Thank you for advice.

Comment: Don't write "solved" in the title, accept the answer that worked instead by clicking the gray check mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set multiple background images with javascript, you set the style only once, but with the string of multiple backgrounds as the value, otherwise each resetting of the style overwrites the previous etc.

```
$("#outer-frame").css({
    'background-position' : 'top left',
    'background-image'    : 'url(images/red/tl.png), url(images/red/tr.png)'
});
```